# Using switch for String in Java 1.6 with different enum type

Tags: java, oop, enums, type-conversion

I'm having code with `if` and `else if` to find some type and create a respective value from it. I wonder how to make it more efficient, I have found the following post in a forum but I don't have a type like `boolean`, my types are `bollean.edm`, `char.edm` etc.

Is there a way to use the following code with adjustment to support my case?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    String typeName = "Boolean";
    String memberValue = "memberValue";
    SwitchInputType type = Type.valueOf(typeName).makeType(memberValue);
}

enum Type {
    Boolean {
        SwitchInputType makeType(String memberValue) {
            return new SwitchInputType<Boolean>(new Boolean(memberValue));
        }
    },
    Double {
        SwitchInputType makeType(String memberValue) {
            return new SwitchInputType<Double>(new Double(memberValue));
        }
    }, 
    Int32 {
        SwitchInputType makeType(String memberValue) {
            return new SwitchInputType<Integer>(new Integer(memberValue));
        }
    };

    // All must do this.
    abstract SwitchInputType makeType(String memberValue);
}

static class SwitchInputType<T> {
    public SwitchInputType(Object o) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please try to explain more exactly what your aim is? What is there to know about your type `bollean.edm` etc?

Comment: I dont think that this is the issue the type should be provided as string ,btw this is Odata type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff478141.aspx), that looks like a documentation to yours misterious `Odata type`. The more or less working sollution should look like this (just change the `String typeName`  values from *standard java.lang.classes* to those `Odata type` whatever ;)):

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
            String typeName = "Edm.Double";
            String namePreparedForEncoding = typeName.replace('.', '_');
            Type type = Type.valueOf(namePreparedForEncoding);
            System.out.println(type);

            String memberValue = "42.99";
            SwitchInputType<?> value = type.makeType(memberValue);
            System.out.println(value);

            String typeName1 = "Edm.Int32";
            String namePreparedForEncoding1 = typeName1.replace('.', '_');
            Type type1 = Type.valueOf(namePreparedForEncoding1);
            System.out.println(type1);

            String memberValue1 = "42";
            SwitchInputType<?> value1 = type1.makeType(memberValue1);
            System.out.println(value1);
    }

    enum Type {
        Edm_Boolean {
            SwitchInputType makeType(String memberValue) {
                return new SwitchInputType<Boolean>(new Boolean(memberValue));
            }
        },
        Edm_Double {
            SwitchInputType makeType(String memberValue) {
                return new SwitchInputType<Double>(new Double(memberValue));
            }
        },
        Edm_Int32 {
            SwitchInputType makeType(String memberValue) {
                return new SwitchInputType<Integer>(new Integer(memberValue));
            }
        };

        // All must do this.
        abstract SwitchInputType makeType(String memberValue);
    }

    static class SwitchInputType<T> {
        private Object o;

        public SwitchInputType(Object o) {
            this.o = o;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "SwitchInputType: " + o.toString();
        }
    }
}
```

output:

```
Edm_Double
SwitchInputType: 42.99

Edm_Int32
SwitchInputType: 42
```

As you may notice, I have replaced `Edm.` with `Edm_` in enums - because enum cannot be names with the dot in the midlle.

PS:

If you change a bit `toString()` method you will be sure that the conversion is really  working:

```
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("SwitchInputType: (%s) %s", o.getClass().getSimpleName(), o);
    }
```

results in: `SwitchInputType: (Double) 42.99`

Hope this helps you